# SetEnvironmentVariable from integer held in a csv cell

Tags: powershell

I have a use case where i want to be able to write a port number to the system environment variable that matches the PC name that the script is being run on.

To do this i have a script that looks for the Computername in a 2 column csv file and writes the corresponding port number of the device to the system environment variable. The problem is that i am unable to get the script to add the port number to the environment variable. 
If i put brackets around the $port in the last line. an entry is added but instead of the port number it adds the string $port. 
If any one could provide some assistance i'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
$COMPUTERNAME = "$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$data = import-csv "C:\PS stuff\Port assign.csv" | Where-Object 
{$_."computer" -eq "$COMPUTERNAME"}
$data | Select -ExpandProperty "port" $port
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TCP_PORT', "$port", 
[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

Comment: `Select -ExpandProperty "port" $port` isn't meaningful. What's wrong with just `$port = $data.port`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the variable $port wasn't being written to due to the way i had structured my code. It has now been changed to the following and all works as required. Thanks for all the assistance.

```
$COMPUTERNAME = "$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$data = import-csv "C:\PS stuff\Port assign.csv" | Where-Object 
{$_."computer" -eq "$COMPUTERNAME"}
$port = $data | Select -ExpandProperty "port"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TCP_PORT', "$port", 
[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$port=Import-Csv -Path 'C:\PS stuff\Port assign.csv'| Where-Object {$_.computer -eq "$COMPUTERNAME"}|Select -ExpandProperty "port"
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.